# How to make jfrog artifactory server as central repository for our project?

Tags: artifactory, devops, artifact-deployer

I am writing a springboot application, which has dependencies of springboot. I want to keep one copy of these dependency into JFrog Artifactory server, so next time dependency will be fetched from JFrog Artifactory server then maven central.

Answer (score 1):

If you are planning to use Gradle as your build tool you can start with the following resources:

- [Introduction to dependency management with Gradle](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/introduction_dependency_management.html)
- [Declaring repositories](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/declaring_repositories.html)
- Artifactory documentation - [Working with Gradle](https://www.jfrog.com/confluence/display/RTF/Working+with+Gradle)
- [Setting up JFrog Artifactory as a Gradle repository](https://jfrog.com/screencast/setting-up-jfrog-artifactory-as-a-gradle-repository-in-less-than-one-minutes/)

In addition you can take a look at the JFrog GitHub for [project examples](https://github.com/jfrog/project-examples). This repository contains multiple example project showing how to work with Gradle and Artifactory.

If you are planning to use [Apache Maven](https://maven.apache.org/) as your build tool you can start with the following resources:

- [Setting up a Maven repository with JFrog Artifactory](https://jfrog.com/screencast/setting-maven-repository-jfrog-artifactory-less-one-minute/)
- Artifactory documentation - [Maven Repository](https://www.jfrog.com/confluence/display/RTF/Maven+Repository)

Comment: Thanks Dror for reply. It will store only our project jar not downloaded from maven central

Comment: It is still preferred that you use some kind of a build tool like gradle or maven which will download/deploy the .jar to Artifactory. If you are currently using ant to build your project, you can use ivy in order to work with Artifactory

Comment: I want to upload all artifact which is available in $GRADLE_HOME/caches/modules-2/files-2.1 to JFrog Artifactory.

Comment: @LalchandMali you do not deploy artifacts directly from the Gradle cache to a repository. I really suggest that you will read more about how to work with Gradle and repositories. I added a couple of links to my answer and a reference to our project examples. Good luck!